# C++/CX - I need to instantiate a Platform::String from a const char*

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I am trying to construct a `Platform::String` from the results of a method that returns `const char*`

I simply cannot get this to work, and have been scratching my head for ages.

Im not a very experienced c++ developer, so the answer may be obvious, but I just cant seem to work it out.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use mbstowcs http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/mbstowcs/ to fill a wchar_t buffer then pass it to the Platform::String constructor to create an instance with the data you want.

```
static wchar_t buffer[ MAX_BUFFER ];
mbstowcs( buffer, source, MAX_BUFFER );
platformString = ref new Platform::String( buffer );
```

Answer (score 3):

`Platform::String` uses `char16` internally, and takes a `char16*` in its constructor. You need to convert your `char*` text to `char16*` text using [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746146/how-to-convert-platformstring-to-char) talks about going from `Platform::String` to `char*`, and to go from `char*` to `Platform::String` the reverse path should be followed.