# Convert Platform::String to std::string

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x, winrt-component

I am getting `String^` which Contains some Indian language characters in a callback from C# Component in my C++ WinRT Component in a Cocos2dx game for Windows Phone 8 project.

Whenever I convert it to `std::string` the Hindi and other characters turn in to garbage characters. I'm not able to find why this is happening.

Here is a sample code and I have just defined `Platform::String^` here but consider it's passed to `C++ WinRT Component` from C# Component

```
String^ str = L"विकास, વિકાસ, ਵਿਕਾਸ, Vikas";
std::wstring wsstr(str->Data());
std::string res(wsstr.begin(), wsstr.end());
```

Comment: Can you keep it as a `wstring`?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT `wstring` content is same as `String^` but problem is when converting it to `std::string` loses encoding of non-english characters,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18374698/4184842) for a better portable solution.

The problem is that `std::string` only holds 8-bit character data and your `Platform::String^` holds Unicode data. Windows provides functions `WideCharToMultiByte` and `MultiByteToWideChar` to convert back and forth:

```
std::string make_string(const std::wstring& wstring)
{
  auto wideData = wstring.c_str();
  int bufferSize = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wideData, -1, nullptr, 0, NULL, NULL);
  auto utf8 = std::make_unique<char[]>(bufferSize);
  if (0 == WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wideData, -1, utf8.get(), bufferSize, NULL, NULL))
    throw std::exception("Can't convert string to UTF8");

  return std::string(utf8.get());
}

std::wstring make_wstring(const std::string& string)
{
  auto utf8Data = string.c_str();
  int bufferSize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8Data, -1, nullptr, 0);
  auto wide = std::make_unique<wchar_t[]>(bufferSize);
  if (0 == MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8Data, -1, wide.get(), bufferSize))
    throw std::exception("Can't convert string to Unicode");

  return std::wstring(wide.get());
}

void Test()
{
  Platform::String^ str = L"विकास, વિકાસ, ਵਿਕਾਸ, Vikas";
  std::wstring wsstr(str->Data());
  auto utf8Str = make_string(wsstr); // UTF8-encoded text
  wsstr = make_wstring(utf8Str); // same as original text
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)  `std::make_unique` is only working with Universal C++ Project for WP 8.1 for the older platform like WP8.0 I have to use char array. I have found an example https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/extensions/GUI/CCEditBox/CCEditBoxImplWp8.cpp

Comment: what's wrong with going all the way with  the standard: std::codevect ?

Comment: @gMorphus, I wasn't aware of that so thanks for the tip (FYI it's `std::codecvt` for anyone else trying to [look it up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0he30td8(v=vs.120).aspx)). Actually it is even easier based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18374698/4184842) to another question.

Answer (score 2):

With C++, you can convert from `Platform::String` to `std::string` with the following code:

```
Platform::String^ fooRT = "aoeu";
std::wstring fooW(fooRT->Begin());
std::string fooA(fooW.begin(), fooW.end());
```

Reference: [How to convert Platform::String to char*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746146/how-to-convert-platformstring-to-char)

Comment: This is the shortest forward way I've found.

Comment: Does this work for the OP's example? The last two statements are basically the same as in the question, and will truncate the wide characters to 8 bits and lose information.

Comment: Use Begin(), not Data()

Comment: @uliwitness you are right, this solution doesn't works with unicode data in platform string.