# C++/CX : Convert std::string to Platform::String^

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cx, windows-rt

Is there a simple way (one line of code would be cool) to convert à std::string to a Platform::String^ in C++/CX ?

I found [how to do it the other way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759212/convert-platformstring-to-stdstring)(String^ to string) but nothing for this one.

Something like :

```
std::string str = "Hello World";
Platform::String^ p_str = convertFromString(str);
```

(In the example it's pointless but when you were working with std::string in c++ and you want to send it to some C# code it makes more sense)

Comment: You could always try and use a charArray to convert between them?

Comment: Sigh, 22 years of Unicode doesn't stop questions like this.  You already know how to convert to std::wstring from that post.  Then it is a one-liner, ref new String(wide.c_str())

Comment: I could make craft something else (with char * etc...), but I wanted to know if there was a good/simple way of doing it

Answer (score 3):

The method works for me

```
Platform::String ^ convertFromString(const std::string & input)
{
    std::wstring w_str = std::wstring(input.begin(), input.end());
    const wchar_t* w_chars = w_str.c_str();

    return (ref new Platform::String(w_chars));
}
```

Comment: Worked for me with slight change in return `return (ref new Platform::String(w_chars, w_str.length()));`

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct `std::string` to `std::wstring` conversion currently possible.

However, we can do a roundabout conversion from `std::string` to `std::wstring`, then from `std::wstring` to `Platform::String` as follows:

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

Platform::String^ stringToPlatformString(std::string inputString) {
  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> converter;
  std::wstring intermediateForm = converter.from_bytes(inputString);
  Platform::String^ retVal = ref new Platform::String(intermediateForm.c_str());

  return retVal;
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18597384/1110928) for more information on `std::string` to `std::wstring` conversion.

Answer (score 1):

If you in the conversion does not like to be limited to Basic Latin (Unicode block), like in my case the need for æøå, this works:

```
#include <sstream>

Platform::String^ StdStringToPlatformString(std::string str)
{
   std::wstringstream wss;
   wss << str.c_str();
   return ref new Platform::String(wss.str().c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically the answer is no : it's more complicated. You need to first convert the std::string in std::wstring and then use user1's answer (convert std::wstring to Platform::String^).
For the string to wstring conversion you can check [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573834/c-convert-string-or-char-to-wstring-or-wchar-t) (which doesn't work for me but whatever, I'll just have to go for a more in depth conversion).

(I had put some code but was told it was terrible to do it like this, since I just do it for debugging and wil delete it anyway I don't care but I don't want to give anti-advice so I deleted that code)