# Pass string like parameter to external method as char *

Tags: c#, c++, windows-runtime

I'm creating Windows Runtime Component (c++) to use it later in windows phone 8.1 application (c#). My problem is preety simple but I cannot find any answer to it:

I need to create a method which take string/char */anything which is filepath  as parameter and pass it to external method which takes char * as parameter.

I've tried with std::string, String^, char *. But I still get errors like such types are not supported (not in String^ case) or some other one.

Is there some simple answer which tells me how should I do this?

**Code samples with errors**

**beginning**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Class1.h"

using namespace Platform;

namespace WindowsRuntimeComponent2
{
    public ref class Class1 sealed
    {
```

various types:

```
int Foo(std::string param) {
```

cause: `Foo': signature of public member contains native type 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' WindowsRuntimeComponent2` and few more containing same information about string's dependencies

```
int Foo(char * param) {
```

cause: `'Foo': signature of public member contains native type 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'    WindowsRuntimeComponent2`

```
int Foo(String^ photoPath) {
```

this one do not cause any errors but I don't know how to parse it to my `char *`.

Comment: You get an error stating `std::string` is unsupported?

Comment: You should post some of your code ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and the error that occurs...

Comment: What character encoding?

Comment: Which type of calling convention are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys, I've added some examples with errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Platform::String to char\*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746146/how-to-convert-platformstring-to-char)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially here you just need to know how to convert from `System.String^` to `std::string`, this can be done in C++/CLI mode as follows:

```
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

//...

int Foo(String^ photoPath) {
    std::string unmanaged_photoPath = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(photoPath);
    // then convert to c-style string as normal using unmanaged_photoPath.c_str();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer I's sure I'm a step closer, but such approach cause some integration problem: `'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll' : WinRT does not support #using of a managed assembly WindowsRuntimeComponent2` in vcclr.h line:16. Do you have any idea of how to handle it?

Comment: @MateuszRogulski I can't be sure without seeing the code structure - does `line 16` correspond to `std::string unmanaged_photoPath = ...` in my answer?

Comment: @ArchibishopOfBanterbury Sorry for missunderstaning, vcclr.h is a file of Windows Runtime Component. In this line we have `#using <mscorlib.dll>`. So I guess your way of parsing uses it.