# UWP Convert String to an Integer

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-cx

Greedings,

I've been looking through everything with google, but i just cannot find an answer.

How can i convert a string "5" to an integer 5 in Universal Windows Platform (UWP) with C++ ?

I've already tried to just convert it by (String^) and so, i know it's pointless but you never know with UWP.

The msdn documentation does not describe anything about type conversions and i just can not find it anywhere. I do not want to do something like String ^ => wchar_t => char -> atoi. Is there a better method for this ? or do i have to do this long memorytaking process ?

EDIT:
It's not the same as you marked... can you read my description before you mark it ? The link you've send is converting std::string to an integer, that's easy, but i need to know how to convert String^ To an int (int32)

Comment: @Sam: I don't think he's asking about converting string→`int` in general, but rather the special case UWP `String^`→`int`. And that's not covered by the potential duplicate (namely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c).

Comment: I suspect the `Platform::String::Data` member function will let you use the ordinary string to int methods such as `std::stoi`. See (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746146/how-to-convert-platformstring-to-char).

Comment: Well, i've ended up with wcstol, but i was thinking about something like ToInt like in C#... something that doesn't use ...tol(str, wcs..) functions

Comment: There's `System::Int32::Parse`. I've not even looked at UWP so I don't know if it's available, but if it is then that's fairly direct.

Comment: @Lukasas Have you looked into using C++'s stringstream?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: `System::Int32::Parse` is .NET (i.e. the managed runtime and platform). UWP, on the other hand, is a native, unmanaged implementation. While it's possible to use a subset of .NET (namely .NET Core), it would be overkill to drag in the entire .NET Core dependency just for this trivial task.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks. I probably need to do some UWP exploration just in order to not sound like a novice. But, I don't really see any future for the idea of single-code-for-all-platforms, it sounds just like Java, maybe with same prime lifetime (10 years?), so I'm pretty hesitant to use time on it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: If you do want to explore the platform, make sure to look into [C++/WinRT](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt), a standard C++ language projection for the Windows Runtime. It's still a fair bit unpolished, lacks support for certain facilities (like XAML), and documentation is scarce. I'd still consider it the most direct way to learn about the platform, without getting distracted by the tooling (like you would with C++/CX or C#).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Platform::String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755812.aspx) (represented as `String^` in C++/CX) provides the [String::Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825860.aspx) member, that returns a `const char16*` to the internal buffer. It can then be used with any standard C or C++ string conversion functions, like [std::wcstol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcstol):

```
long ToLong( String^ str ) {
    const wchar_t* begin = str->Data();
    return std::wcstol( begin, nullptr, 10 );
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to implement some error handling, and ensure that the entire string is interpreted, you could write:

```
long ToLong( String^ str ) {
    const wchar_t* begin = str->Data();
    const wchar_t* end = str->Data() + std::wcslen( str->Data() );
    wchar_t* last_interpreted{ nullptr };
    long l = std::wcstol( begin, &last_interpreted, 10 );
    if ( last_interpreted != end ) {
        throw ref new InvalidArgumentException();
    }
    return l;
}
```

Note, that no additional memory is allocated. The conversion function operates on the stored sequence of the `Platform::String`.

If you can spare a potential temporary memory allocation, you could use [std::stol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), and get proper error reporting for free:

```
long ToLong( String^ str ) {
    return std::stol( { str->Data(), str->Length() } );
}
```

Comment: [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) provides error checking and is very simple to use. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: It is, indeed. But it is at the mercy of the optimizer, to produce an equally zero-overhead conversion. The `const std::wstring` may (or may not) have to allocate an extra copy. Whatever, I'll just add it for completeness.